# Transform class

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is the Transform class defined? What members and functions does it have? I have been able to find the Transform**s** class, but not the Transform class.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10575/transform-class/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf::Transform is a [typedef](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h_source.html#l00055) for a Bullet [btTransform](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTransform.html)  class.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2